# telegraf http input plugin

Tags: influxdb, telegraf, telegraf-inputs-plugin

I am trying to create a proof on concept using the TICK stack for monitoring. I have the helloworld stack running and showing CPU/Docker metrics.

I am trying to use the telegraf [http input plugin](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/tree/master/plugins/inputs/http) to pull from an http endpoint:

From the docs i have simply configured the URL, GET and type (Set to json)

```
[[inputs.http]]
## One or more URLs from which to read formatted metrics
urls = [
"http://localhost:500/Queues"
]
method = "GET"
data_format = "json"
```

However nothing appears in Influx/Chronograf. 
I can modify the endpoint to suit any changes there, but what am i doing wrong in telegraf config ?

Comment: I am having a similar issue with this plugin: https://community.influxdata.com/t/when-using-tick-charts-telegraf-s-i-cannot-use-the-inputs-http-plugin/4740

Answer (score 1):

I think I had the same struggle. For me the following conf worked:

```
[[inputs.http]]
name_override ="restservice_health"
urls = [
   "https://localhost:5001/health"
]
method = "GET"
data_format = "value"
data_type = "string"
```

In this way, it appeared in Influxdb under the name "restservice_health" (allthough this option is not important for the example, so you could leave it out).

Answer (score 0):

First, you would have to look at the result of the `http://localhost:500/Queues` request to make sure that it's a valid JSON object.
Then, depending on what is returned from that endpoint, you may have to configure the [JSON parser](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/tree/master/plugins/parsers/json), for example by setting `json_query` to a [GJSON query](https://github.com/tidwall/gjson/tree/v1.3.0#path-syntax) to navigate the JSON response to the data you need.